# WiFi подключиться к роутеру без кабеля после сброса настроек reset

Tags: wifi, роутер

Здравствуйте. Есть WiFi роутер Asus RT-N53S. Я сбросил на нём все настройки методом кнопки reset на задней панели. Как теперь к нему подключиться без кабеля и настроить его? На ноутбуке сетевая карта неисправна.

Comment: Извините, если я не по адресу обратился. Нигде этой проблемы не встречал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите на самом роутере, в инструкции, в интернете имя сети и пароль по умолчанию. Если по умолчанию Wi-Fi отключен, то без кабеля никак.

Answer (score 0):

Никак не получится, кабель нужен обязательно при настройке